# Failed to read dockerfile - .NET 5.0

Tags: docker, dockerfile, .net-5

I am new to Docker, and this issue has me completely stumped. None of the online solutions are working for me, so any help would be appreciated.

So I am trying to build a docker image for a .NET 5.0 web application that also references a class library project. This is for a Linux container on a Windows machine, and Docker Desktop has been set to 'Linux containers'.

This is my directory structure-

I have my solution file here:

```
D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer\HostServer.sln
```

The main web application project is located here (also contains the Dockerfile):

```
D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer\HostServer\HostServer.csproj
```

The class library project is located here:

```
D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer\QuicktronWrapper.csproj
```

Visual studio created the following Dockerfile in `D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer\HostServer\`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["HostServer/HostServer.csproj", "HostServer/"]
COPY ["QuicktronWrapper/QuicktronWrapper.csproj", "QuicktronWrapper/"]
RUN dotnet restore "HostServer/HostServer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/HostServer"
RUN dotnet build "HostServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HostServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HostServer.dll"]
```

and a .dockerignore has been created here:

```
D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer
```

I know that all projects should be in the same build conext for Docker, so I run the following command from D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer

```
docker build -f D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer\HostServer -t hostserver .
```

But I get the following error:

```
[+] Building 0.0s (2/2) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from HostServer                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 20.52kB                                                                            0.0s
 => CANCELED [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring context:                                                                                       0.0s
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: read /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount468265171/HostServer: is a directory
PS D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer>
```

I know it has something to do with the Dockerfile.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has shown in the error "HostServer: is a directory". It requires a file, not a directory. You can refer to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#specify-a-dockerfile--f)

Please try to run the command by providing explicitly a Dockerfile name `docker build -f HostServer\Dockerfile -t hostserver .` from the directory `D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer` as you did.